# Pass an array of nids to a view

Tags: 7, views

How do I pass a view an array of node ids?  I can create the view using the ui, but the query I want to run is outside the scope of views.  I want to run the db query independently, gather the node ids into an array, and then pass it to the view for display.  Howvian I make this happen, if at all?

Comment: Can you please explain this a little more? You can to create a view that shows a in each row a different node?

Comment: thanks guys... These are great answers. I get quicker and better answers here than on drupal.org!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a "Content: Nid" contextual filter to your view, so your view will narrow down the content to the NIDs you provided. Make sure you check the "Allow multiple values" box when configuring the contextual filter. This will allow a url like `example.com/myview/12+45+78` which would limit the results to node IDs 12, 45 and 78.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display these nodes formatted with a view_mode, and not for example in a table, you could also use the API for that: [node_view_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view_multiple/7).

Simply pass the array of nid's with the desired $view_mode to that function and it will return an render array that you can return in a block or page callback or directly render with `drupal_render()`.